# Bash running background commands within a script

Tags: bash, shell, background, command

I need to run a deletion in the background within a shell script.

The folder I'm deleting is large and would take too long if the command was done in the foreground

at the moment the script is

```
...
...
mv /somefolder /somefolder_old ;
nohup rm -Rf /somefolder_old &
...
...
```

The command is performed in the foreground.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup rm -Rf /somefolder_old & mv /somefolder /somefolder_old; .......
```

`nohup rm -Rf /somefolder_old &` this will execute in the background while at the same time `mv /somefolder /somefolder_old` is being executed

example try the following codes in a shell

```
 while :;do echo hello;sleep 1;done & while :;do echo John;sleep 1;done
```